# Does the model name agree with the architecture of this server via /proc/cpuinfo?

Tags: linux, redhat, fedora

Ignoring the model name, it appears this **cloud server** has 4 single core processors without hyperthreading.

However the model name indicates that it's quad core.  I'm not the system admin so I didn't buy this instance of a cloud server, nor have I been configuring it.  Doesn't this look a little off though?

```
$ sudo cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep -iE "physical ID|processor|core id|core|model name|sibling" | sort

core id         : 0
core id         : 0
core id         : 0
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
cpu cores       : 1
cpu cores       : 1
cpu cores       : 1
model name      : Quad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2374 HE
model name      : Quad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2374 HE
model name      : Quad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2374 HE
model name      : Quad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2374 HE
physical id     : 0
physical id     : 1
physical id     : 2
physical id     : 3
processor       : 0
processor       : 1
processor       : 2
processor       : 3
siblings        : 1
siblings        : 1
siblings        : 1
siblings        : 1
```

Here's the documentation from AMD for this product
http://products.amd.com/en-us/OpteronCPUDetail.aspx?id=518&f1=&f2=&f3=Yes&f4=&f5=&f6=&f7=&f8=&f9=&f10=&f11=&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The physical CPU is a quad-core processor. The virtual CPU is four single-core processors. The physical and virtual CPU layouts do not have to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal for vCPUs. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Does vCPU mean virtual CPU?  Is it 4 single core CPUs with no hyperthreading or is it a quad core?  Why is it normal for a vCPU to have the specs be different than what the manufacturer's specs?

Comment: @LedZeppelin I think that you need to read about how virtual CPUs work in virtual environments. Also, if you gave the downvote, I think it's mildly inappropriate.

Comment: I didn't give a downvote...

Comment: @LedZeppelin Ok. No prob, it just happened at the same time that you added your comment. :)